# Static method invocation via Method.invoke() gave me NPE

Tags: java, reflection, protocol-buffers

I'm dealing with Google Protobuf messages.

Since my needs are to set instance fields of an Object (some of them are Protobuff messages), I've wrote a function that retrieve via reflection the builder and through the [protobuf-java-format](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/) recreates the message.

Here's the code

```
for (String aFieldName : objectContentMap.keySet()) {
 Object aFieldNameValue = objectContentMap.get(aFieldName);
 if (aFieldNameValue != null) {
  Field theClassField = this.instance.getField(aFieldName);
  ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(theClassField);
  Class<?> classType = theClassField.getType();
  if (!classType.isPrimitive() && 
   GeneratedMessage.class.isAssignableFrom(classType.getSuperclass())) {
   Method method = classType.getMethod("newBuilder");
   // Since the method is static, the instance object that undergoes the call is not important, but with "null" I have a NPE...
   Object builder = method.invoke(new Object()); 
   if (builder instanceof Builder) {
    Builder newBuilder = (Builder)builder;
    InputStream asd = new ByteArrayInputStream(((String)aFieldNameValue).getBytes());
    protoMapper.merge(asd, newBuilder);
    aFieldNameValue = newBuilder.build();
   }
  }
  theClassField.set(recreatedObject, aFieldNameValue);
 }
}
```

This snippet works as intended, but my doubt is in the `Object builder = method.invoke(new Object());` line since when I call static methods I've always put `null` as actual parameter.

In this scenario I've a NullPointerException.

Have someone any idea why there is the need of a instance in the invoke() actual parameter?

Thanks Dario.

Comment: If invoke throws NPE, then the method is not static. You may want to check whether Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())

Comment: @Javier: I've already check the method modifier. The control gave me unfortunately true.

Comment: my main doubts are in the protobuf part. I've not so much experience in these genereted classes...

Comment: Why do you need to mess around with protobuf objects with reflection?

Comment: @LouisWasserman because this piece of code is part of an aspect that serialize/deserialize classes annotated in a particular way. These classes can have fields that are `GeneratedMessage`s.
The strange thing is that `newBuilder()` is static but throws an exception if I don't put the `new Object()` thing...

Comment: Why don't you show the stack trace?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov here's:java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at it.sayservice.platform.annotation.processing.core.type.FieldOrAccessorMethodsProperty.jsonToProto(FieldOrAccessorMethodsProperty.java:171)
at it.sayservice.platform.annotation.processing.core.util.DeepClassFieldInspector.changeInstance...

Comment: Anyway this question has only a knowing purpose since, luckily, I've no issues with new Object()...

Comment: Are you sure the string "Object builder = method.invoke" is at it.sayservice.platform.annotation.processing.core.type.FieldOrAccessorMethodsPro‌​perty.jsonToProto(FieldOrAccessorMethodsProperty.java:171) ?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for Method says the Method.invoke method signature is:
"invoke(Object obj, Object... args)"

It also says:
"If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null."

This means that your underlying method is NOT static. However you are checking to see if it is static it is not correct.